# Upload png to FTP with batch file not working

Tags: batch-file, ftp, png

I have a batch file (fileup.bat) to upload a PNG file to my server:

```
@echo off
echo user USERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo PASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd "public_html/DOMAIN.com/test/test1/test2">> ftpcmd.dat
echo put IMAGE.png>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat DOMAIN.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Then, I call this batch file from another batch file (test.bat):

```
fileup
```

However, it does not work. It does nothing at all. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this at the top, and not on the command line.  makes the second line append into the file also then.

```
echo open ftp.domain.com> ftpcmd.dat
```